# Создание массива не зная его будущий размер

Tags: массивы

Задача такова, вводится последовательность чисел оканчивающаяся нулем, например: 1 2 3 4 5 0, так вот, я не имею понятия сколько будет продолжаться ввод чисел отличных от нуля. Я хочу эти числа хранить в массиве. По логике я:

```
// объявляю массив.
int[] array;

// решаю наполнять его через цикл.
int i = 0;
int j = scanner.nextInt();
while (j != 0) {
    array[i] = j;
    j = scanner.nextInt();
    ++i;
}
```

По мне очень логичное решение. Я понимаю, что если j изначально будет 0, то массива так и останется неинициализированным. По итогу, как поступают в данном случае? Спасибо!

Comment: Неплохо бы язык указать. А то например на js с этим никаких проблем нет.

Comment: создают массив с одним элементом. если вставляется второе значение, то создают новый массив (больше по размеру), копируют старый в новый, удаляют старый

Comment: В lua тоже с этим проблем нет. Там и массивов собственно нет :D

Answer (score 1):

В c++:

1. используем контейнеры stl: `std::vector`, `std::list` и т.д.
2. сначала определяем сколько элементов нужно, потом создаем динамический массив:

   ```
    int* arr = new int[arr_size];
   ```

в python:

1. используем список `list`

и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

При достижении конца массива как правило создают новый, в два раза больше текущего, копируют туда данные и продолжают наполнять до достижения конца. Дальше всё повторяется.